# I want to add Two numbers on my Fragment2.It is possible to add two number on same fragment and display?

Tags: android-fragments

Here i am using,edittext1 for accepting sum1 value and edittext2 for accepting sum2 value.I want to add two number on same fragment and display in same fragment in textview1.an i am getting error message like :-

```
08-14 00:22:49.222    6866-6866/com.bijay.ilirccalculator E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.bijay.ilirccalculator, PID: 6866
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
            at com.bijay.ilirccalculator.MyFragment2$1.onClick(MyFragment2.java:43)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4803)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20102)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:810)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:189)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5529)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
```

//fragment2.java
 @Override

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_fragment2, container, false);
    //Accessing button by its id
    Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.calcbutton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
       //Action onclick
        public void onClick(View view) {
            EditText sum1 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            EditText sum2 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            //Declaring variables 
            double  Sum1,Sum2,Total;
            //Converting input variables to double sum1 and sum2
            Sum1 = Double.parseDouble(sum1.getText().toString());
            Sum2 = Double.parseDouble(sum2.getText().toString());
            //Adding sum1 and sum2
            Total= Sum1 + Sum2;
            //Passing value of total to textview1
            TextView t = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            t.setText("The Sum of Num1 and Num2" + Total);
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: can u please help me with improvement  code ??